# EXPORTING A MAP REPORT TO EXCEL OR PDF

Tags: google-maps, canvas, export-to-excel, export-to-pdf, webpage-screenshot

i am an Brasilian Web Developer, and i am making an report of phone calls geolocation in an virtual PABX ( asterisk ), already working fine with google maps API V3.

**OBJECTIVE** Export this report into a PDF or Excel, so i am thinking in turn the map into a image, to export after:

What i already try:

- Create a Static Map dont solve my problem because i have a marker for each calls, and i am clustering markers with MarkerClusterer
- I converted my map in Canvas using [html2canvas](http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/), after my html turned in canvas i used [canvas2image](http://www.nihilogic.dk/labs/canvas2image/) to create an `<img>` element, for simple html this solution works perfect, but in case of google maps the result is that:

Unfortunately i cannot post images because i have no reputation, i always visit StackOverflow but its my first time making a question, but i can describe that the image generated from the canvas have just the gray google maps background and the number of markers of the markerclusterer.

You can see the image here to understand better:

[image]

I am thinking in something like take a screenshot of the page and crop to just pick map region, but any sugestions that can solve the problem or give me a way will be very welcome.

Comment: You will probably have to consider an extension/add-on for the browser(s). Both Chrome and Firefox has the ability to do screen capture using the canvas, but this is only allowed from within an extension.

Comment: Well noticed, very thanks, i am considering use something like FREE web services like http://grabz.it/api/php/  but in this case i dont know how to crop just the map area from the screen

Comment: If you just need to crop it I can provide you with an example, but as long as you need to take out the canvas content as an image CORS will kick in unless the free service allows their service being used cross-domain or you can provide the snapshot from the same origin (basically the same domain as the page is running from).